# Netlogo: Calculate the diameter of a graph/network

Tags: netlogo

In the model I am currently developing is a graph/network based model and the diameter is required. Is it possible for the diameter to be calculated? The diameter will be found using links. For example a line graph of 5 nodes would have a diameter of 4, this becomes more complex with random graph's. 
This is a qoute of the diamter:

> The shortest distance between the two most distant nodes in the
>   network. In other words, once the shortest path length from every node
>   to all other nodes is calculated, the diameter is the longest of all
>   the calculated path lengths.

I have tried to design this but unable to implement this. Any advice or examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the networks extension for NetLogo (see http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/nw.html). Unfortunately, it doesn't have the diameter as one of the built-in functions, but you can calculate the distances between each pair of nodes and take the maximum.

Comment: JenB: How can the number of pairs be calculated? If possible will try and implement the faster method. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Thanks I have used two foreach loops to calculate the paths of one turtle to the rest.